# How to calculate these two contour integrals?

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $\gamma_1(t) = t+i/\sqrt{2R}, 1/\sqrt{2R} \le t\le R$, and

$\gamma_2(t) = R - t - i/\sqrt{2R}, 0 \le t\le R-1/\sqrt{2R}.$

Suppose $f(z) = \log(z)/(z^2+6z+8)$, where $\log z$ is defined on $\mathbb C \setminus \{x: x\ge 0 \}$ by $\{\log(re^{i\theta}) = \log r + i\theta, \text{when } 0 < \theta< 2\pi, r>0\}$.

How do we obtain $\int_{\gamma_{1}} f(z)dz + \int_{\gamma_{2}} f(z)dz \to -2\pi i \int_0^\infty \frac{dt}{t^2+6t+8}?$

The book says $\log(x+i/\sqrt{2R}) - \log(x-i/\sqrt{2R}) \to -2\pi i$ as $R\to \infty$. How do we get this?

Comment: For your second question, it is because we are approaching the branch cut of the logarithm from opposite sides. Your first question follows from the second along with a little observation about the geometry of the contours.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Could you elaborate? I don't see how these work

Comment: I don't have the time atm to write up an answer, but perhaps someone else does. Is there a specific textbook you are using? I can take a quick look and point you in the right direction at least

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen It is on page 136 of Function Theory of One Complex Variable by Greene & Krantz. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Thanks. I got 10 minutes free, checked out the book online, and quickly wrote up an answer. Let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we wish to calculate $\int_{[0,\infty]} \frac{1}{t^2 + 6t + 8}$ via the method of residues, we immediately run into a problem: the integrand has no poles on the region of integration. Normally our goal is to decompose things in such a way that all integrals cancel except our residues, but that strategy simply cannot work if there are no residues to work with.

The second problem is that we want "most" of our contour to stay away from the origin in order for the integrals to vanish, but without using the negative real line we are forced to come back along an arc to the origin. With some integrands this is fine since we can, for example, come back along a slanted line on which our integral is simply a multiple of the integral on the real line - for example, this is the case with
$\int \frac{1}{1+x^3}.$ This would be quite complicated here though, so we have to consider other ideas. In some cases we can relate our integral along the positive axis to an integral along the whole real line, which seems promising since our integrand is even, but there is a problem here: our integrand is symmetric about $-3,$ not the origin. We could maybe force this to work, but it does not sound appealing.

This leads to the idea of a Keyhole Contour of radius $R$, which has the advantage of easy $ML$ estimates to ideally show the circular integrals around $C_\epsilon$ and $C_R$ vanish (where $C_r$ is the disk of radius $r$ - technically punctured here, but if one checks in full formality one finds this is unimportant).

If we try to use your integrand as is, we can get a little ways in, showing the two integrals around the circles vanish, but run into a problem: how do we relate $\int_\epsilon^R \frac{1}{t^2+6t+8}$ with $\int_R^\epsilon \frac{1}{t^2+6t+8}$? It can perhaps be done, but the trick is to add a logarithm.

Why do we do this? Define $\mathcal{L}(z)$ to be the general logarithm with positive branch cut, i.e. $\mathcal{L}(z) = \log|z| + i\arg(z)$ (we have to account for any multiples of $2\pi i$ in the general case). Note that if we integrate just above the branch cut we have $\mathcal{L}(z) = \log(z),$ i.e. the standard branch of the logarithm with a positive branch cut, while if we integrate just below the branch cut we will have $\mathcal{L}(z) = \log(z) + 2\pi i$ since our argument has augmented by $2\pi i$ as we went around the circle. Thus we have
$$\int_R^\epsilon \frac{\mathcal{L}(z)}{t^2+6t+8} = \int_R^\epsilon \frac{\log(z) + 2\pi i}{t^2+6t+8} = \int_\epsilon^R \frac{-\log(z) - 2\pi i}{t^2+6t+8}$$
so that
$$\int_\epsilon^R \frac{\mathcal{L}(z)}{t^2+6t+8}+ \int_R^\epsilon \frac{\mathcal{L}(z)}{t^2+6t+8} = \int_R^\epsilon \frac{\log(z) - \log(z) - 2\pi i}{t^2+6t+8} = -2\pi i\int_R^\epsilon \frac{1}{t^2+6t+8} $$

We can now calculate any residues inside our contour and use them to evaluate this integral.